# Why the [value] is not working when using the directive for mobile number?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I am using the directive to validate the mobile number input

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mobileNumber]'
})
export class MobileNumberDirective {

  @Input()
  public value: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

        var inp = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        if (/[0-9]/.test(inp)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (event.keyCode == 8 || (event.keyCode == 43 && this.value == '')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The input field is this :

```
<input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Search Mobile"
       autocomplete="off"
       [value]="'1111199999'"
       mobileNumber
/>
```

here, the [value] is not working when the directive is applied but working fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bi-directional in Ui, So once you assign the direct value (number or string) will not work.

```
<input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Search Mobile"
       autocomplete="off"
       [value]="value" <-- bind your property
       mobileNumber
/>
```

Please refer the [Link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html)

I hope this solution is clear to you

Comment: this is not working, if i remove directive everything is fine but when apply the directive it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** indicate to your directive that the element show the "value" (you can see more clear if you choose as name of your input, e.g. "myValue")

You can implements OnInit and write

```
ngOnInit{
  this.el.nativeElement.value=this.value;
}
```

BTW, you're using a directive not for validate, else to avoid keydown a "not number".

We can use the ngOnInit also to check at first if value fullfilled the condition.

```
ngOnInit{
  if (this.value)
       this.el.nativeElement.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
}
```

Well, you can also use `[(ngModel)]` to have a two-binding to get the value of the variable (also you can use `[attr.value]` instead of [value] and remove the `@Input() value`from your directive

To use either, [(ngModel)] or [value] you directive can be like

```
  @Input()
  public value: any;

  //see in constructor how inject a "NgControl"
  constructor(private el: ElementRef,@Optional() private control:NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
       ...
    }

ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if (this.control)
            this.control.control.setValue(
                        this.control.value?this.control.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''):
            '')
        else
            this.el.nativeElement.value=this.value?this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''):
            ''
    })
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkbgys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmovile.directive.ts)

**Update** In the case we're using an @Input `[value]`,instead use ngOnInit we can use a getter or ngOnChanges. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter)

```
  _value: any;
  @Input('value') set _(value) {
    this._value = value;
    this.el.nativeElement.value = value ? value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') : '';
  }
  public get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
```

Or

```
  export class MobileNumberDirective implements OnChanges 
  {
     ...
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
         const value=changes['value'].currentValue
         this.el.nativeElement.value=value?value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') : ''
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **RegexFormate** Validation and after set **[maxlength]="10"** like this this is good option to add validation

**Example :**

```
 <div class="input-fields">
          <mat-form-field class="min-field" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Mobile No (First)</mat-label>
            <input matInput [formControl]="mobile1" [maxlength]="10" appRegexFormate regexType="number"
                   autoComplete='off' [(ngModel)]="merchantModelAdd.mobile1" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="mobile1.hasError('required')">Mobile No (First) cannot be
              empty
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="mobile1.hasError('pattern')">Invalid mobile No (First)
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

---

**Regex Class**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRegexFormate]'
})
export class RegexFormateDirective {
  @Input('regexType') numericType: string;
  private regex = {
    number: new RegExp(/^\d+$/),
    letter_only: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/g),
    letter_space: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/g),
    letter_num: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g),
    letter_num_space: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/g),
    letter_num_special: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-@#$%^&*!()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+$/g),
    remark: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-@#$%^&*!()_+\-=\[\]{};:\\,.<>\/? \n]+$/g),
    url:  new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/g),
    decimal: new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g),
    email: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_.]+$/g),
    long_lat_number: new RegExp(/^[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]{0,5})?$/g)

  };
  private specialKeys = {
    number: ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight'],
    letter_only: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    letter_space: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    letter_num: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    letter_num_space: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    letter_num_special: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    remark: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight'],
    url: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    decimal: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    email: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
    long_lat_number: [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ],
  };

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys[this.numericType].indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex[this.numericType])) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown2(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const current: string = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    if (current) {
      if (!String(current).match(this.regex[this.numericType])) {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = '';
        setTimeout(function (evet) {
          element.click();
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

---

***use like this this is best option***

Comment: You needn't wait 100 miliseconds. When you use setTimeout(()=>{..do something..}) -without time argument- you say to Angular that execute a new "cycle" after repaint. BTW 1.-you can use "flat arrow" instead of `function(event)`, 2.- you can use an unique "specialKeys" array,

Comment: Not valid answer above question you say another thing but question is another. If you have any question please create new post and share with me link i will give you to answer

Comment: it's only a comment about the code in your answer. BTW the original question is about because if you use an `@Input() value` it's not change the html element, and the answer is that you need change the html element.